# IPv6 address get function?

Tags: c

`unsigned char networkMask [sizeof (struct in6_addr)] 
      = { [0 ... (sizeof (struct in6_addr) - 1)] = 0xff };`

what does `(0...(sizeof))` is representing here. How this array is allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular syntax is a GCC extension of the [designated initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). With it, you can initialize an array like this:

```
unsigned char foo[<n>] = { [0 ... <n> - 1] = <k> };
```

*Whereby `<n>` is the number of members and `<k>` is any given member value.*

In the code you have shown, it initializes the `networkMask` array with `0xff` for elements from index `0` through `sizeof(struct in6_addr) - 1`. In other words, it initializes an array with the size of [`struct in6_addr`](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/in6.h#L30) and sets all bits to `1`.

It would be equivalent to this, given that an IPv6 address occupies 16 bytes:

```
unsigned char networkMask[sizeof(struct in6_addr)] = { 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255 };
```